# How to change the file upload folder in apache tomcat?

Tags: file, tomcat, maven, upload

Tomcat 6.29 creates a folder under `temp` folder in apache tomcat, and when I uploaded a file with the path `req.getSession().getServletContext() + specified folder` but when the application is redeployed another application folder is again created so the previously uploaded files stay at the older deployed application. I want to upload files under `webapp folder/app_name` but at that time I take the specified doesn't exist. I wonder if it is possible to upload and retrieve the files under the `webapp/app_name`.

Note: application is developed with spring+hibernate and deployed with maven.

Comment: It's not clear for me that your application receives the uploaded files and save them or you do it by hand, for example with scp/ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use a relative path in your file handler code. Go up with ../../.. etc. Or you can make a direct server request against the old app from within your handler - servlet to servlet, for example.

Comment: thanks Roger,but i think tomcat uses the files under temp/app_name folder because i tried to change jsps under that folder and the tried again from browser they changed.I rearrange my question as usage of which folder in tomcat is normal for such applications.

Comment: It seems to me that you're asking whether you can take control of where your files are stored; specifically whether you can store them in a subdirectory under your webapp. Yes you can. You don't need to getServletContext() to do it. Here's a copy-paste from one of my servlets that specifies a fixed location for files within the app directories:   private static final String DEFAULT_FILE_PATH = "../webapps/myApp4/new_articles/";